# Check if at least two array values are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, equals

I'm actually looking for a way to check if two values of an array or more are equal. Here are some examples :

```
[1, 2, 3] // false
[1, 1, 5] // true
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'] // true
[10, 10, 10] // true
```

I found this function that gives 'true' if EVERY array values are equal, but that's not what i'd like :

```
[1,1,1,1].every( (val, i, arr) => val === arr[0] ) // true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Set` to eliminate duplicates:

```js
const nonUnique = a => new Set(a).size !== a.length;

console.log(nonUnique([1, 2, 3])); // false
console.log(nonUnique([1, 1, 5])); // true
console.log(nonUnique(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'])); // true
console.log(nonUnique([10, 10, 10])); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be create a `Set` of the unique values and compare `size` of Set to `length` of array

```js
const hasDuplicates = (arr) => new Set(arr).size < arr.length ;

console.log(hasDuplicates([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(hasDuplicates([1, 1, 5]));
console.log(hasDuplicates(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']));
console.log(hasDuplicates([10, 10, 10]));
```

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is pretty inefficient (O(n^2), brute force search), but it works:

```js
function has_dupes(arr) {
  return arr.some((x, i) => arr.includes(x, i+1));
}

console.log(has_dupes([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(has_dupes([1, 1, 5]));
console.log(has_dupes(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']));
console.log(has_dupes([10, 10, 10]));
```

For every element `x` at some index `i`, we check whether the subarray starting at `i+1` includes another value that's equal to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop we can break the loop once we find a duplicate.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3] // false
var b = [1, 1, 5] // true
var c = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'] // true
var d = [10, 10, 10] // true


function diff(arr){

    var diff = []
    
    for(let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(diff.includes(arr[i])){
         return true;//<-- break the loop   
        }else{
            diff.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return false;

}

console.log(diff(a))
console.log(diff(b))
console.log(diff(c))
console.log(diff(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a double for loop where one is the index of what is being looked for and the inner loop checking for a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Add them to a set while checking using the `find` method

```js
let items1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4];
let items2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let items3 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
let items4 = [0, 0]
let items5 = [undefined, undefined]

function hasDuplicate(array) {
  const set = new Set()
  return array.some(it => {
    if (set.has(it)) {
      return true
    } else {
      set.add(it);
      return false;
    }
  })
}

console.log(hasDuplicate(items1))
console.log(hasDuplicate(items2))
console.log(hasDuplicate(items3))
console.log(hasDuplicate(items4))
console.log(hasDuplicate(items5))
```

Comment: :) Thanks will fix

Comment: @melpomene Nice catch BTW :)

Comment: New version doesn't work for `hasDuplicate([undefined, undefined])`.

Comment: @melpomene That's true.  Can you find any holes in my other answer?

Comment: @melpomene I used a closure and ignored the returned valued.  Seems to work, yes?  Could have just used a for loop and a break...

Comment: Now it's just a weird way of writing `array.some()`.

Comment: @melpomene Schooled again!  Thanks!  I forgot about that one.  I'm liking my other answer better though...

Answer (score 0):

You can find all unique elements through lodash and just compare the size of both the arrays to get what you want.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a_uniq = _.uniq(a); //will return [1, 3]
console.log(a.length != a_uniq.length); //will return false

a = [1, 1, 3]
a_uniq = _.uniq(a); //will return [1, 3]
console.log(a.length != a_uniq.length); //will return true
```

Can test here quickly: https://codepen.io/travist/full/jrBjBz/

Answer (score 0):

You can loop it easily using `for loop` for example:-

```
function hasDuplicate(lst){
    for(var i=0; i<lst.length; i++)
        for(var j=i+1; j<lst.length;j++)
            if(i!=j && lst[i] === lst[j])
                return true;
    return false;
}

var list1 = [1,1,5];
window.alert(hasDuplicate(list1)); //True
```

Comment: You don't need to rescan from the start each time in the inner loop. You can start from `var j=i+1` because the elements before `i` were already checked for duplicates by the outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the array into an object with keys being the items. If the object's keys are a different length than the items length, there are duplicates.

This also gives you an indication of the number of duplicates.

```js
const items1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
const items2 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
const items3 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const items4 = [undefined, undefined]

function dupCount(array) {
  const obj = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item] = true;
    return acc;
  }, {})
  return array.length - Object.keys(obj).length
}

console.log(dupCount(items1))
console.log(dupCount(items2))
console.log(dupCount(items3))
console.log(dupCount(items4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isSameArray(data, count) {
   var result = false;
   data.forEach(a => {
      const filter = data.filter(f => f === a); 
      if (filter.length > count - 1) {
         result = true;
         return;
      }
   });

   return result;
}

isSameArray([1, 2, 3], 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Array.some works the same as Array.every, except if the test passes true for one of the items in the array you're iterating over, execution stops and it returns true. Probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

The following will help you in achieving the result which u gave as an example:

```
Array_is_true(int *a,int n)
{
   int j=1,flag=0;
  for(int i=0,i<n;i++)
   {
      j=i+1;
      while(j<n;)
      {
         if(a[i]==a[j])
         { flag=1;j++;}
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is that supposed to be?

Comment: If this is supposed to be C, I count 3 hard errors that prevent the thing from even compiling. Apart from that, there are at least 2 severe bugs in the algorithm that prevent it from working correctly ("severe" because the first bug makes it go into an infinite loop).

Comment: its in c++ @melpomene